# Does this download link provide all the components like sdks along with?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

The size of the latest Android studio use in around 1GB. So I was thinking if it contained all the components needed to run and develop apps with it

Here's the link
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/3.3.1.0/android-studio-ide-182.5264788-windows.exe

Comment: Click https://developer.android.com/studio/ and click on the download button. It contains everything you will need for now.

Comment: You will need to install the desired SDK that you intend to build your app on

Comment: Yes, it is. But, make sure you download from the link given by @NongthonbamTonthoi.